# How to add javascript snippet in angular2 template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am new to angular2 development. I would like to add the below js lines inside my footer.component.html (angular 2).

But the code is not running in angular 2. Can somebody help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feedjit.com/serve/?vv=1515&amp;tft=3&amp;srefs=0"></script>

<noscript><a href="http://feedjit.com/">Live Traffic Stats</a></noscript>
```

Comment: Have you tried https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html#!%23bypassSecurityTrustScript-anchor

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Can you provide sample code with this api..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add those scripts in your index.html

Once you add your JavaScript in the head of your index.html , your whole application will have access to it.

If you need to refer to it in your components. You should declare a variable for it and it will become available for you.

For example, lets say you import some JavaScript that brings an object that you want to use and call methods on it. Let's call this object obj1. In your component you would declare this variable after your imports(not inside your class)

```
declare var obj1: any;
```

Now in your component you can use this object and call methods on it.

Comment: I want to add these lines inside of my footer component also i am calling some other components after footer component. So it is not an good idea to add js lines in index.html file. Can you provide alternate idea please.